# Find all polynomials over R such that $P(x+3) = 3 + P(x)$. This seems quite trivial, but i can't find a way to solve it mathematically, any help?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Find all polynomials over R such that $P(x+3) = 3 + P(x)$. This seems quite trivial, but i can't find a way to solve it mathematically, any help?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Surely you have found some examples, at least.

Comment: Hint: Consider what happens to $|P'(x)|$

Answer (score 1):

First you can make some observations :

$$P(3)=3+P(0)$$
$$P(6)=3+P(3)=6+P(0)$$
$$P(9)=3+P(6)=9+P(0)$$
And so on, you can see that $P(3k)=3k+P(0)$ for any integer $k$.

Now let $Q=P-X-P(0)$. Then $Q(3k)=P(3k)-3k-P(0)=0$. This means $Q$ has infinitely many roots and thus $Q=0$. In other words :

$$P(X)=X+P(0)$$

And you can choose $P(0)$ arbitrarily.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Suppose
$$ P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^k
$$
Then $P^{(n-1)}(x)=n!a_n x+(n-1)!a_{n-1}$. So $P(x+3)-P(x)=3$ implies the derivatives are all $0$.
Since $P^{(n-1)}(x+3)=n!a_n (x+3)+(n-1)!a_{n-1}$, then we have $a_n=0$.

Then considering the other derivatives, we can get $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq 2$. Then it is easy to show $a_1=1$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Can you elaborate on explain why "$P(x+3) - P(x) = 3$ implies that the derivatives are all 0"?  In particular, the solution $P(x) = x$ has a non-zero first derivative.

Comment: Since $P(x+3)-P(x)=constant$, derivatives of constants are 0. Comparing $P^{(n-1)}(x+3)$ and $P^{(n-1)}(x)$, we have $a_n=0$

Comment: For example, $P(x) = \sin (2\pi x)$ satisfies $P(x+3) - P(x)=$ constant, but $P'(x) \neq 0$. So, while it may be true for polynomials, you need to further explain why it holds for polynomials.

Comment: All that you have is $P'(x+3) - P'(x) = 0$, but you're using $P'(x) = 0$. $\quad$ In fact, it is not 0, since the solution is $P(x) = x + k$ and $P'(x) = 1$ (which satisfies $P'(x+3)-P'(x)=0$). This indicates that there is a mistake in your approach.

Comment: I am not using $P^{'}(x)=0$. I said comparing $P^{(n-1)}(x+3)$ and $P^{n-1}(x)$ the difference is $3n!a_n$, so $a_n=0$.

Comment: What i am trying to do is essentially the same as Cuman above.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that $P(x)$ has degree $n \geq 2$. Then we can write $P(x)$ like so:
$$
P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_kx^k
$$
Which means:
$$
P(x+3) = a_0 + a_1x + 3a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_k(x+3)^k
$$
The problem states that $P(x+3) - P(x) = 3$ which means:
$$
3a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_k(x+3)^k - \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_kx^k = 3 \\
$$
Now we need to show that $\sum_{k=2}^{n} a_k(x+3)^k - \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_kx^k$ isn't a constant function. Let's expand it.
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n} a_k(x+3)^k - \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_kx^k \\
= \left( \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_k \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i}(3^i)x^{k-i} \right) - \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_k x^k \\
= \left( \sum_{k=2}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^k (a_k) \binom{k}{i}(3^i) x^{k-i} \right) - \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_k x^k \\
= \sum_{k=2}^{n} \left[ \left( \sum_{i=0}^k (a_k) \binom{k}{i}(3^i) x^{k-i} \right) - a_k x^k \right] \\
= \sum_{k=2}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^k (a_k) \binom{k}{i}(3^i) x^{k-i}
$$
It seems that there's only one $x^{n-1}$ term, and its coefficient isn't zero, which would imply that this isn't a constant function. To find the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the above expansion, we need to find the appropriate $k$ and $i$ such that:
$$
\begin{cases}
k - i = n - 1 \\
2 \leq k \leq n \\
1 \leq i \leq k
\end{cases}
$$
We can only have $i = 1$, since if $i \geq 2$ then we will have $k = n - 1 + i \geq n + 1$, which contradicts with $k \leq n$. Therefore, $k=n$ and $i=1$. It follows that the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is $((a_n) \binom{n}{1} (3^1))$, which is not zero. Now we can say that $P(x+3) - P(x)$ isn't a constant function. So $P(x)$ must have degree $1$, or $0$. Each case can be easily checked.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why is "a sum of non-constant functions is also a non-constant function"? In particular, the non-constant functions $x$ and $-x$ do sum to the constant $0$.

Comment: woops, my bad. Thanks @CalvinLin for mentioning the counter-example. I was a bit careless to write that statement. I have added a proof showing it is non-constant.